# Is this (enum : char {}) a gcc bug?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, enums

under gcc-4.5, it prints 0, under gcc-4.6, it prints 1.

```
#include <iostream>

enum VenueId: char {}; 
int
main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
  VenueId v = (VenueId)'P';
  std::cout << (v=='P') << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would guess a conversion like that is undefined, but I can't find the proper standardese `:-(`

Comment: It's well-defined. GCC 4.5 was buggy.

Comment: With the latest version of g++-4.5 in Ubuntu 12.04 this was obviously fixed, as it prints out 1 as well. Also the assembly generated (Intel style) is nothing more than `mov BYTE PTR [rbp-0x1],0x50` which corresponds to `VenueId v = (VenueId)'P';` and `cmp    BYTE PTR [rbp-0x1],0x50`, corresponding to the comparison, and as you can see, `0x50 == 0x50`.

Comment: with respect to C++11 features, my rule of thumb is: gcc 4.5 = pre-alpha, 4.6 = alpha, 4.7 = beta, 4.8 = release

Answer (score 5):

As per standard, **`VenuedId` has `char` type as underlying type**, so `v` should contain char `'P'`, `v == 'P'` should yield *true*.

§ 7.2 Enumeration declarations

> Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other types. Each enumeration also has an underlying type. **The underlying type can be explicitly specified using enum-base**; if not explicitly specified, the underlying type of a scoped enumeration type is int. In these cases, the underlying type is said to be fixed. **Following the closing brace of an  num-specifier, each enumerator has the type of its enumeration.**

Comment: So is it a bug in GCC then?

Comment: It was, as stated in the comments of the question.

Comment: a paragraph about the ability to store any member of the underlying type in the enum would perfect this answer.

Comment: 7.2/7 "For an enumeration whose underlying type is fixed, the values of the enumeration are the values of the underlying type. [...] It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators."